# Pass multiple arguments to Page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, playwright, webautomation

I have the below Playwright-TS code. I am passing email id dynamically to the tester method and I want it inside page.evaluate but email:emailId in the below code errors out as undefined.

```
  apiData = {
    name: faker.name.firstName(),
    domain: process.env['DOMAIN'],
  };
```

```
async tester(page: Page, emailId: string)
    {
      await page.evaluate((apiData) =>
      { 
          const authentication = {
          userId: window.localStorage.getItem('userId')
        };

        const data = 
        {
            email:emailId
        };

        fetch(`${apiData.domain}/api/v1/user`, 
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
           cookie: authentication.allCookies,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(myJson => {
          newUserId = JSON.stringify(myJson.data.id).replace(/\"/g, "");
            
      },this.apiData);
    }
```

I tried passing it as:

```
await page.evaluate(([apiData, emailReceived] =>
   { 
    },[this.apiData, emailId]);
```

But then apiData values throws error -  Property 'domain' does not exist on type 'string'.

I tried other solutions but none seems to work for me. How can I implement this?

Comment: This works for me. Can you  share a complete, runnnable, [mcve] please?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `emailId` to the `apiData`:

```
await page.evaluate(([apiData, emailReceived] =>
  { 
  },
  {
   ...this.apiData, 
   emailId
  });
```

And then you will be able to use `apiData.emailId` inside the function you are evaluating.